# Adding subViews to UISplitViewController

Tags: ipad

I have this button on the leftside of my UISplitViewController (RootViewController) that has a "Add New" button. I want the user to be able to click the button a new view come pop up so the user can add a new RSS feed to their subscription. So far I have the button and the "Add New" button correctly calling a method in the controller, but there's no way for me to add superviews or subviews. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for UISplitViewController.viewControllers.  Something like this will allow you to access the subviews for the left and right panels of the split view controller.  Assuming `splitViewController` is your split view controller:

```
UIViewController* leftController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
UIViewController* rightController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* leftView = leftController.view;
UIView* rightView = rightController.view;
```

Afterwards, you can add subviews in the normal way to `leftView` and `rightView`.